# How to navigate from one screen to another without onpressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

Can you tell me some way that how can i navigate from one screen to other in flutter without on button pressed.
I am using ternary operator when condition is true after getting response from API, it show me circular progress indocator and when it becomes false it navigate to new screen.

```
     _con.loading 
                  ? Padding(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(55),
                           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                  : 
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/FindingDriver', 
arguments: RouteArgument(param: _con.order.id, param2: _con.order.foodOrders.first.food.restaurant.id)),
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the app architecture, but the simplest solution might be to add a post-frame callback on the screen like that:

```dart
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final response = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First'),),
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second'),),
        body: Container(),);
  }
}
```

As an alternative, consider to leverage `FutureBuilder` and replace not the entire screen, but it's content only.

Comment: Even with FutureBuilder, post frame callback can be used to navigate.

Comment: The above methods giving me an error of mediaquery. Kindly edit the code again.

Comment: Ted Henry can you show me the code, how to do that? It will be a great help